# Keeping backend version history using a mechanism similar to entity framework database migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I need to have a table in my database to keep the backend (Web API) versions history. In fact, every time there is a change in the code (a new version), I want to create something like entity framework `database migration` so that it executes only once at the first application run and stores the version(s) in the backend version history table.

I can use EF database migration mechanism for this purpose using the `Sql` method in a new empty migration `Up` method:

```
public override void Up()
{
   Sql(@"
         Insert into Cor.BackendVersionHistory (Version, Description, Author, ReleaseDateTime, DeploymentDateTime)
         Values ('1.10.1', 'Version Description', 'Author Name', '2019/05/06 11:00:00', getdate())
      ");
 }
```

But it doesn't seem right since it's supposed to be used for database specific migrations.

I was wondering if there is a right way of doing this using a similar scenario to EF migrations.

Comment: I think migrations are a very good way to solve this, why don't you like using it? If it's because of the sql, you can create your own custom migration, and do something like: `migrationBuilder.UpdateApiVersion([list of params])`. If your API version is stored in the db, then it is a database "specific" migration. What is nice as well, it's that if you create a migration for a new API version, you can create a tag (in git) for that version and the migration will be part of it.

Comment: Say you have versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2. You may want to run API on version 1.1. You just check out the appropriate tag and apply migrations.